# iOS Universal Link not working even after it passes all validation. Do we need to test this only after app release?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-links

I followed all the steps mentioned in App Search Programming Guide to enable Universal Link in my application, but its not working.

Steps Followed:

1) Apple app site asscoiation file is created and accessible from the web.

2) Enabled Associated Domains in the member center and generated the provisioning profile.

3) Added `applinks:limeroad.com` in the capabilities section of my app target.

4) Implemented -

```
-(BOOL)application:
 (UIApplication *)application continueUserActivity:
 (NSUserActivity *)userActivity restorationHandler:
 (void(^)(NSArray * __nullable restorableObjects))restorationHandler
```

5) Tried opening below links from mail app but they always open in Safari.

```
www.perf.limeroad.com/scrap/s56b1d03f092d275b2808c6d5
```

6) Tried long pressing in the link and it only shows open in safari, but not open in my app.

My app supports iOS 7 onwards. I have tested these steps with the development build as well as test flight build, but it never worked for me.

I tried four square and make my trip app and they seem to be working fine. I tried this in my iPhone 6 running iOS9.2 and iPad running iOS 9.1.

Did validation with `search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool/` and seems like things are fine here too.

Please let me know what i have missed here. Is anyone else facing the same issue?

```
JSON: { 
        "applinks": { 
          "apps": [], 
          "details": [ { "appID": "TB98D47W8J.com.limeroad.Limeroad",
                         "paths": ["*"] 
                       } 
                     ] 
        } 
}
```

App Validation :

[image: App Validation]

Xcode Applinks addition :

[image: Xcode Applinks addition]

Comment: Hi, Were you able to get any where with this? I am seeing exactly same behaviour with my app. I am able to open links from Gmail, but after hitting "Open the app" multiple times in safari.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I got this working in one app but a newer app is not working (we support iOS8 not 7 but same issue basically). Did you make sure the entitlements are in the bundle? I found out it doesn't automatically get included.....but that didn't fix the problem for me either.

Answer (score 1):

Did you add these entitlements to your project.entitlements file? And after you add the entitlements to that file make sure that you include that file to the build targets.

Comment: Good tip! We had separate entitlements files and one was missing the domains. However the problem still remains.

Comment: @PeterLamberg , The URL www.perf.limeroad.com/scrap/s56b1d03f092d275b2808c6d5
does not seem to be leading anywhere ... Is this the URL that you're testing universal Linking with? Neither does http://www.perf.limeroad.com. That can be a problem.